# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollview not scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, endlessscroll

When I'm scrolling down, the items above the `RecyclerView` does not scroll unless I start touching from the layout above, and it only scrolls down when I have reached the end of the RecyclerView.

```
<NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout>
        <Some other items.../>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RecyclerView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</NestedScrollView>
```

**Note:**
I actually use a fixed size for the RecyclerView, setting it via the code below:

```
float height_recyclerview = (ScreenUtil.getHeight(context) - (height_banner + height_bottom_navigation + height_create_post));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) height_recyclerview);
rv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**Why** do I use fixed size if it works smoothly with `wrap_content`?

- I will be displaying possibly thousands of items that may have
  images, which will hurt performance if it does not actually do
  recycling because of the issue that the `RecyclerView` is inside the
  `NestedScrollView`
- I have implemented an EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener which has an
  issue that it keeps loading more data from server continuously if
  implemented with a RecyclerView that is within whatever scrollable
  view, or if it is in a scrollable view, but does not have a fixed
  height, even if you are not scrolling down.

**I have tried** the following:

- set nested scrolling to false on the recycler view
- try using scroll view instead of nested scroll view
- a bunch of other code related to layouts and scrolling behaviors that others suggested which didn't work for me because I'm implementing it in a much more complicated layout and the fact that I use EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener

**What** I want to fix?

I want to make the page scroll like a single page, not as a separate scrollable view.

Note that my recycler view has a fixed height that takes the entire screen's space meaning that its height is actually fit assuming that the linear layout above is not visible anymore if the user has scrolled down.

The ideal scenario is to make the scrollview scroll down first, to make the recycler view take the entire screen, so that the recyclerview will scroll however the user wants to.

Then the linearlayout above which should not be visible anymore if the recycler view has taken up all the space of the screen, should only show up if the recycler view has reached the top/first item, if the user keeps scrolling back up.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView)

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your recycler xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/conversation"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I did not disable nested scrolling. But my issue is that the layouts above the recycler view does not scroll accordingly. 

And.. If I disable the nested scrolling. The recycler view wont scroll at all.

Comment: Still works the same. My goal is to make the scrollview scroll down first, until the recyclerview fits the screen. So that my recyclerview will then scroll as the user wants it. And that the linearlayout above will only show again if the recyclerview reaches the top if the user keeps scrolling back up.

Comment: @Rick, did you ever figure out the solution for the behavior you desired? I wish to do the same..

Answer (score 0):

**NestedScrollView Smooth Scrolling**

```
recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
```

Do this programmatically

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        ...
```

Comment: I have tried disabling nestedscrolling. And for some reason, the recycler view does not scroll at all because my recycler view has a fixed size. It does however scroll fine if the recyclerview is implemented with wrap_content. This is why I leave it enabled. And with nested scrolling enabled. I have the issue that I just posted above.

Comment: @Rick did you add that line?

Comment: Yes I just tried it but sadly, it still doesnt work that way I want it. It's still the same

Comment: Okay what is your UI requirement?

Comment: Make the nested scroll view scroll down even if I started touching inside the recyclerview. Because If I start touching inside the recyclerview and then scroll, only the recyclerview scrolls down.